# How to attach window into the main window using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to know how to make my second window attach within my main window.
this is what i have done so far. i can't attach the second window into the main window

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Main Window")
width_value = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height_value = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width_value, height_value))

def new():
    floor_plan = Toplevel(root)
    floor_plan.title("Second Window")
    floor_plan.geometry("500x500+100+200")

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)
        fileMenu = Menu(menu, tearoff = 0)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="New", command=new)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)

app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you have `width_value = ...`, `height_value = ...` and then `root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width_value, height_value))`? You can just use `root.geometry("+0+0")`. Its much simpler and faster

Comment: Also you don't need the `self.master = master` line. Tkinter will do that for you.

Comment: What do you mean by you want to attach the second window to the main one?

Comment: @TheLizzard i just want to get the full screen window if I run the program. but I'll take note of that one. thanks

Comment: So you want the second window to be full screen? Is so try: `root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)`

Comment: @TheLizzard what i mean about attaching the second window to the main is that if I open the second window its parameter will just be at the main window. means that if i move the second window it will just show inside the main window

Comment: Why would you want that? You could just create a frame inside the first window and place your widgets inside of it. But if your still want this, then check `'<Configure>'` bind.

Comment: Are you asking about what used to be called a "multiple document interface" where you have one master window, and inside that you have children windows that exist only inside the main window (ie: movable, but all within the master window)?

Comment: @BryanOakley yes. how to i do that?